# Split dotted path but replace two dots with a symbol

Tags: javascript

In my domain-specific language, I am able to reference something inside a tree-like structure using a dotted path, except that I can also go "up" with two dots in a row:

```js
"sibling"         // gets sibling
".sibling"        // same as above
".sibling.nested" // indexes into sibling with 'nested'
"..down"          // goes up the hierarchy, then down the key 'down'
"down.."          // doesn't do anything, really, goes down and then back up
".."              // references parent
"down..down"      // same as "down"
```

I need to split the above like this:

```js
["sibling"]
["sibling"]
["sibling", "nested"]
[symbol, "down"]
["down", symbol]
[symbol]
["down", symbol, "down"]
```

In essence, replacing the `..` with a symbol, but splitting by single `.` normally. I can split plain dotted nested paths like this (even respects escaping the period):

```js
path.split(/(?<!\\)\./)
```

**Keys can potentially contain any characters, so a word boundary will not work sometimes.**

But I'm having a hard time finding a clean solution that can replace the `..`. My current solution is to replace all empty strings with the symbol (empty strings mean that there were two periods in a row), and append a character to the ends of the path, removing after the splitting is done:

```js
const symbol = Symbol();

function split(path) {
  path = "$" + path + "$"; // Any character can work; I just used '$' here
  // Split by dots, replacing empty strings with the symbol
  const split = path.split(/(?<!\\)\./).map((part) => (!part ? symbol : part));
  // Remove prefixed character from start
  split[0] = split[0].slice(1);
  // Remove suffixed character from end
  split[split.length - 1] = split[split.length - 1].slice(0, -1);
  // Remove start or end if they are empty
  if (!split[0]) split.shift();
  if (!split[split.length - 1]) split.pop();
  // Done
  return split;
}

const tests = [
  "sibling"        , // gets sibling
  ".sibling"       , // same as above
  ".sibling.nested", // indexes into sibling with 'nested'
  "..down"         , // goes up the hierarchy, then down the key 'down'
  "down.."         , // doesn't do anything, really, goes down and then back up
  ".."             , // references parent
  "down..down"     , // same as "down"
];
// (Stack Overflow snippet console displays null instead of Symbol)
console.log(tests.map(split));
```

It gets the job done, passes all the test cases, but it's much too verbose and clumsy. I'm looking for a hopefully shorter and easier solution than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My trick is to split on `.` and `..`, but include the last `.` if it exists

```
const symbol = Symbol();

// Your function
function split(path) {
  path = "$" + path + "$"; // Any character can work; I just used '$' here
  // Split by dots, replacing empty strings with the symbol
  const split = path.split(/(?<!\\)\./).map((part) => (!part ? symbol : part));
  // Remove prefixed character from start
  split[0] = split[0].slice(1);
  // Remove suffixed character from end
  split[split.length - 1] = split[split.length - 1].slice(0, -1);
  // Remove start or end if they are empty
  if (!split[0]) split.shift();
  if (!split[split.length - 1]) split.pop();
  // Done
  return split;
}

function split2(path) {
  return path.split(/(?<!\\)\.(\.)?/g) // Split on . and .., but include the last . if exists
             .filter(s => s) // Remove falsey things
             .map(s => s === '.' ? symbol : s)
}

const tests = [
  "sibling"        , // gets sibling
  ".sibling"       , // same as above
  ".sibling.nested", // indexes into sibling with 'nested'
  "..down"         , // goes up the hierarchy, then down the key 'down'
  "down.."         , // doesn't do anything, really, goes down and then back up
  ".."             , // references parent
  "down..down"     , // same as "down"
];
console.log(tests.map(split));
console.log(tests.map(split2))
```

Output

```
[
  [ 'sibling' ],
  [ 'sibling' ],
  [ 'sibling', 'nested' ],
  [ Symbol(), 'down' ],
  [ 'down', Symbol() ],
  [ Symbol() ],
  [ 'down', Symbol(), 'down' ]
]
[
  [ 'sibling' ],
  [ 'sibling' ],
  [ 'sibling', 'nested' ],
  [ Symbol(), 'down' ],
  [ 'down', Symbol() ],
  [ Symbol() ],
  [ 'down', Symbol(), 'down' ]
]
```

EDIT:

1. Better algorithm, better writing
2. Change from including the first `.` to the last `.` as it just sounds more natural to do. (Should be no difference in usage)

Comment: This is nice, I didn't think that something this simple could work. I edited the regex to respect escaping the periods as well.

Comment: @catgirlkelly Glad I could help! I am not entirely sure how the `(?<!\\)` works, but wouldn't a simple `\\?` do the trick as well? Making the regex `\\?(\.)?\.`

Comment: That's just an optional backslash, `(?<!\\)` is called a **negative lookbehind assertion**. It's asserting that there are no backslashes before the dots. You can find more about this [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly (at least my solution also passed all the tests), here is my shorter version:

```js
let f = str => str.split(/\b/g).filter(x=> x!='.').map(x=> x=='..'? Symbol() :x);
const tests = [
  "sibling"        , // gets sibling
  ".sibling"       , // same as above
  ".sibling.nested", // indexes into sibling with 'nested'
  "..down"         , // goes up the hierarchy, then down the key 'down'
  "down.."         , // doesn't do anything, really, goes down and then back up
  ".."             , // references parent
  "down..down"     , // same as "down"
];
console.log(tests.map(f));
```

Quick explanation:
I suggest that every tree node is a single 'word' then I split the string by word boundaries which is easy with help of regex's `\b` and the rest is obvious I guess

UPD.

My 2d version that could handle even `'asd.$..a#123s.asdasd'` to correctly translate it into `[ 'asd', '$', Symbol(), 'a#123s', 'asdasd' ]` is here

```js
const f = str => str.split(/(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)/gm).map(x=> x.split(/\.\./).flatMap(e => [e,Symbol()]).slice(0,-1)).flat();

const tests = [
  "sibling"        , // gets sibling
  ".sibling"       , // same as above
  ".sibling.nested", // indexes into sibling with 'nested'
  "..down"         , // goes up the hierarchy, then down the key 'down'
  "down.."         , // doesn't do anything, really, goes down and then back up
  ".."             , // references parent
  "down..down"     , // same as "down"
  "asd.$..a#123s.asdasd", //add test with any symbol inside
];

console.log(tests.map(f));
```

The main idea behind my second variation is to firstly find single `.` (before or after which there are no extra dots) and split by it.
So with my example we will transform `"asd.$..a#123s.asdasd"` into `["asd", "$..a#123s","asdasd]`.
The socond part as easy as first. We have to split the rest by `..` and insert the `Symbol()` in between.

P.S.`slice(0,-1)` prevents redundant `Symbol()` at the end of each sub array.

Comment: This is really short and sweet, works perfectly, but I'm sorry I forgot to include that the keys could potentially contain any character. I will update the question.

Comment: @catgirlkelly updated my answer with long-long one-line function (xD) that could handle names from any characters

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works for you, but I get the same output on your tests.
It's only 2 lines less and little more readable though.

```js
function split2(path: string) {
    path = path.replace('..', '.$.')
    let split = path.split('.').filter(x => x)
    split = split.map(function(x){return x === '$' ? symbol : x});
    return split;
}
```

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbARiANjAvDAyk1aAFAJQDcAUOQGYCuYwUAluHAA5qNSGsCGUAFgC44UAE6MwAc2IwA3uRgxeArDABEAEjUwA1Er79d6rRUWhIsCO06rl-AHRWOXAPSEA-AB4AhAB1fxL72LsT2iDyshNw8olDCPGDwMpgAfDCE3ryxMO5w+OgwwllQxGQKbM4A2gAMALqqTpw1tY4cwACmhACMZYqNUJX99mjtUioAtDBd9dj9g9ZQw6OSE1MtEG2d1QA0MOM9pjCMVOnec3UyQxD8x1y9RycZc0MjY4aT05cL9qwgkfeidpQGiiMAVTgUAC+lFo9CYLH6ACZogJhNBxFIZPJFIo7LYDPZAeweB1CAByez2Mm7CkaKnEcqKEaWBb4gSOBbk+n2KiMNBQdqiQgADywaVF3kw2DJZIZOPBsFm33CkVhDGYYBFxFkgOBoJgoql0o0ZJyeRQBWEwsh90UupBYP6UMo5mgMAF0Agqkq5TUEEYyA4Um08pxuxcLhgkiBXv9gYkkl9jgDQckIdD4cjEB4iHaMB4Xp4qAAbu0k3HU-YwO1oO0ACZqTNHMB19rCmvNqAgOAphMwADunEMZOrtbrZKT9jrIH7YHToZgTckIA7NFY7v4eZugpiwH48F2AlGMGns43eYA1u14DAyaewBPFGp75T5xmYBGTyuIA-YNP84kAgJrsgI8GgaAHlG35fmeCR1ueYLICSF4wGuk5vguihNoCVCCqMHRelkoxQL6L5TjOc7vp+2a5vmXrPhRajkLUFCfoQOBQMhMAAPKlqIVBoDOcBgIwrCsECMCuugeZ1owTg8PAXpgDQ4HNrWPDwSAJx4BaaAMlJIzDCAkiEB6UAQGEESEP0pQUAZ7RGSZZkWSq1kLIitlAA).

Comment: It's a nice idea but if there was a key originally named `$` then this would produce the wrong output (any characters possible in key names).